# UnrecognizedClientException error when I try to enable "time to live" on local DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface

I use local DynamoDB on Docker and I want to set up a time to live (**TTL**) feature for the table.

To table creates I use:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
    --table-name activity \
    --attribute-definitions \
        AttributeName=deviceId,AttributeType=S \
        AttributeName=time,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema \
        AttributeName=deviceId,KeyType=HASH \
        AttributeName=time,KeyType=RANGE \
    --billing-mode 'PAY_PER_REQUEST' \
    --endpoint-url http://dynamo:8000
```

And it works as need.

But when I try to enable TTL:

```
aws dynamodb update-time-to-live \
    --table-name activity \
    --time-to-live-specification Enabled=true,AttributeName=ttl
```

I got the error: `An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the UpdateTimeToLive operation: The security token included in the request is invalid`

Dummy credentials for the Docker I sent using docker-compose environment:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 0
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 0
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-central-1
```

Used Docker images:

- For DynamoDB - dwmkerr/dynamodb
- For internal AWS CLI - garland/aws-cli-docker

What is wrong? How can I enable the feature using local Docker?
Thanks for any answer.

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an extra a few hours of failures, I have an answer. I hope it helps somebody save a bit of time:

- Even if you use a local environment, you should use real AWS
  credentials (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY). You can get it [here](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup) after register.
- If you use `--endpoint-url` parameter
  for creating DB, then you should use it with the same value for
  `update-time-to-live` or any other action for the DB.

Cheers!

Comment: Isn't the missing " --endpoint-url" your only problem?
If the create-table operation worked with `--endpoint-url` but *without* the key setup, then so should the update-time-to-live, no?

Comment: No, the main problem was a dummy credential. Though the local DynamoDB allows creating a table, but don't allow to use TTL with the one.